# Should Postgres COPY FROM be updating BRIN index?

Tags: postgresql-9.6

Imagine a table like...

```sql
create table study_value (
    id serial primary key,
    study_id int not null references study (id),
    category text not null,
    subcategory int not null,
    p_value double precision not null
);
```

I knew it would have 25+ million rows and they needed to be quickly queryable by the parent study as well as optionally by category and subcategory, so I chose to add a BRIN to it.

```sql
create index study_value_idx
    on study_value using brin (study_id, category, subcategory);
```

All data for a given study (1mil+ rows) was inserted in bulk (ordered by category/subcategory) from a buffer via...

```sql
    copy study_value from stdin with (format csv, header false);
```

This study data was uploaded sequentially in order of study id, so the insert orderings fully respected the BRIN column order.

**The problem I'm seeing** is that querying this table on conditions that the BRIN satisfies, eg. `select count(*) from study_value where study_id = 3;`, is performing a full scan and taking 30+ seconds. The size of the BRIN itself is 48 kb.

If I `reindex index study_value_idx`, however, queries now take ~100 ms and the index size is over 100 kb.

Everything I've read (in PG docs, on SO, etc.) indicates that one should **only** need to reindex in very specific situations (eg. data corruption or indexes failing to build).

I did not need to drop the index before loading data and re-create it afterward, because copying 1 million records into the table only took 10 seconds.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that prior to running reindex, I ran `analyze study_value` and saw no change.

Comment: What you should do after a bulk load is to run `analyze` on the table

Comment: Ah, updated my post - I forgot to mention that I ran `analyze` after seeing slow query and saw no change in query plan or index

Comment: Does `vacuum analyze` afterwards change anything?

Comment: Oh man, I forget that every time... Yep, `vacuum analyze` did the trick.

Comment: I'm a little confused; I thought `vacuum` was only to reclaim space from dead tuples? There aren't any updates or deletes on this table.

Comment: It also updates statistics and the visibility map (which in turn influences the usage of indexes)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, my mistake. I needed to `VACUUM ANALYZE` per @a_horse_with_no_name's comment.

I re-created the table and re-imported data. On fresh load, index size is again 48 kb and query is back to ~30 seconds. **I had misread** the query plan, though - it *does* use the index, the actual rows are just wildly different from expected.

```
Aggregate  (cost=231550.86..231550.87 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=32233.141..32233.156 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Bitmap Heap Scan on study_value  (cost=6226.26..229546.26 rows=801840 width=0) (actual time=6555.954..27253.035 rows=781580 loops=1)
     Recheck Cond: (study_id = 920)
     Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 22027434
     Heap Blocks: lossy=213169
     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on study_value_idx  (cost=0.00..6025.80 rows=801840 width=0) (actual time=16.345..16.352 rows=2132480 loops=1)
           Index Cond: (study_id = 920)
Planning time: 0.941 ms
Execution time: 32233.266 ms
```

After `analyze study_value` (3 sec) the idx is still 48 kb and query plan is:

```
Aggregate  (cost=231360.49..231360.50 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=25468.247..25468.259 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Bitmap Heap Scan on study_value  (cost=6161.41..229376.81 rows=793472 width=0) (actual time=2740.866..20419.470 rows=781580 loops=1)
     Recheck Cond: (study_id = 920)
     Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 22027434
     Heap Blocks: lossy=213169
     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on study_value_idx  (cost=0.00..5963.04 rows=793472 width=0) (actual time=17.301..17.306 rows=2132480 loops=1)
           Index Cond: (study_id = 920)
Planning time: 0.101 ms
Execution time: 25468.389 ms
```

After `vacuum analyze study_value` (20 sec) the idx is now 112kb and query plan is..

```
Aggregate  (cost=231496.34..231496.35 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=10038.873..10038.884 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Bitmap Heap Scan on study_value  (cost=6228.78..229501.25 rows=798037 width=0) (actual time=12.303..5133.281 rows=781580 loops=1)
     Recheck Cond: (study_id = 920)
     Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 17962
     Heap Blocks: lossy=7473
     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on study_value_idx  (cost=0.00..6029.27 rows=798037 width=0) (actual time=1.644..1.650 rows=75520 loops=1)
           Index Cond: (study_id = 920)
Planning time: 0.511 ms
Execution time: 10038.993 ms
```

Executing a more detail query (ie. including category/subcategory) is much faster, maybe ~400 ms.